# Getting inner nested list from HTML

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on a converter for HTML to OOXML and I'm having some issues with nested lists for which I'm trying to use regex to grab them.

Imagine the following use cases for list items

1. `<li>Hi</li>` - Just some text, should ignore
2. `<li><ul><li>hi</li></ul></li>` - Directly in `<li>`
3. `<li>Hi<ul><li>hi</li></ul></li>` - Plain text before the nested list
4. `<li><strong>Hi</strong><ul><li>hi</li></ul></li>` - HTML content before the nested list

https://regexr.com/3rvch takes care of `2.` and `3.`, but I can't seem to get `4.` sorted. The main issue with 4 is that it needs to also allow HTML tags, but it needs to ignore `</li>`. I've been trying along the lines of https://regexr.com/3rvem, but can't get it to work.

The regex needs to grab:

1. The content after the initial `<li>`, before the `<(ul|ol>`
2. The `<ul|ol>` block with its content

Comment: Your given regex which you say works for 2 and 3 doesn't seem to work for any of them, except for 1 which it ignores as it should. It's matching the whole query on 2 and 3 and nothing for 4. The examples you've given here are different to the ones you've linked

Comment: You'd probably need some [recursive regex like this one](https://regex101.com/r/cUlrP7/1).

Comment: Thanks @bobblebubble! I'm fairly decent at regex, but there's some nice new stuff in there for me to learn, looks good! I see that the capture groups are different, but that's fine, because I can get that from the callback function

Comment: @Richard I put it as answer as it seemed of help for your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this idea by use of a [recursive regex](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html) for capturing the nested tags in combination with a [conditional](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-conditionals.html) to dismiss those which don't contain `<[uo]l>`. It's a bit experimental but seems work.

```
<li>(?>[^<]+|(<[uo]l)>|<(?!\/?li)[^>]*>|(?R))*<\/li>(?(1)|(*F))
```

- `(<[uo]l)>` the first [capturing group](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html) captures the list tag if present inside `<li>`
- `(?R)` means: paste the entire regular expression right here (recursion)
- `(?(1)|(*F))` means: [if group 1 set](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-conditionals.html#check_numgroup) OK, do nothing, else FAIL `(*F)`=`(?!)`

[See this demo at regex101 for testing](https://regex101.com/r/cUlrP7/1) (it can fail on large input as it's a rather slow regex)

Comment: What would you define as large btw? We're working with WYSIWYG input from users, that could be quite "large"..

Comment: @Richard you can watch the stepscounter increase on the regex101 demo for larger input until it fails.